# Avoid keep finding dom which belong to jquery multiple form unique id

Tags: jquery, dom, find

My page has multiple form which placed in `<li>` and I assign them an Unique ID then in my jquery I feel
tired and make code messy when keep finding the dom which belong to the id.
like below

```
var id = $(this).parent().closest('li').attr('id');
var $formID = ('#' + id);

$form.find('foo').addClass('bar');
     .find('foox').hide('barx');
     .find('fooy').etc('bary');
     .find('fooz').etc('barz');
etc.....
```

Any idea that I can make code looks better?

Comment: IDs can be @undefined :D

Comment: @undefined yes, they are unique. Then I am really tired and bored keep using .find(), otherwise the action will select all the classes name in the page which with multiple forms

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can use find to search a sub-set of the dom from a jQuery object.  You can also use a space in a full selector to find a child.  So the following is the same as your code:

```
$(formID + ' foo').addClass('bar');
$(formID + ' foox').hide('barx');
$(formID + ' fooy').etc('bary');
$(formID + ' fooz').etc('barz');
```

Is this what you are asking?